# Why does it throw an index out of range error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am tryng to make a game object move back and forth between three points,this is in unity in C#,I assigned 3 game objects in the unity inspector,I want the enamy GameObject to move between the points back and forth like a patrol.The problem is that i get an index out of range error. Why is that and how can i fix it?
Sorry for possible gramatical mestakes.

Here is my code:

```
public class Enamy2 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] pointPosition;
    public float enamySpeed;
    private int currentPoint;
    private bool backTracking = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        transform.position = pointPosition [0].position;
        currentPoint = 0;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (transform.position == pointPosition[currentPoint].position) {
            if (backTracking)
                currentPoint--;
            else
                currentPoint++;
        }
        if(currentPoint >= pointPosition.Length) {
            backTracking = true;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, pointPosition [currentPoint].position, Time.deltaTime * enamySpeed);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IndexOutOfRangeException` happens in two cases: the index is either too large or too small.  You can't use negative indexers in C#.  You have this:

```
    if(currentPoint >= pointPosition.Length) {
        backTracking = true;
        currentPoint = pointPosition.Length - 1;
    }
```

Now you need to add this directly afterwards:

```
    if(currentPoint <= 0) {
        backTracking = false;
        currentPoint = 0;
    }
```

The additional line to clamp the `currentPoint` to the boundary position ensures that it is within bounds before the next line is called.

At this point if you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` then it would be because the pointPosition[] is empty and has no elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your `currentPoint` becomes too large. You even have checking:

```
if(currentPoint >= pointPosition.Length) {
    backTracking = true;
}
```

but beside setting `backTracking` to `true`, you don't do anything about it and in your next line you are using `pointPosition[currentPoint]`. If it became greater or equal to `pointPosition.Length` it is out of range.

Comment: How should i modifye the script so i cand get the desiered outcome? I did unity and C# for only like a week so it's hard for me...

Comment: You need to reset `currentPoint` within the if statement.  Example: `backTracking = true; currentPoint = 0;`  Or you handle backTracking differently.

Comment: Actually, you _also_ have to make sure that `currentPoint` is never negative.  Add an if statement to turn off backTracking if `currentPoint` reaches 0.

Comment: @DinuAdrian, that depends what you want to accomplish. I never used Unity so I can't recommend anything but you should check `if(currentPoint >= pointPosition.Length || currentPoint < 0)` and handle that case in any way appropriate to what you are making.